# Can I tell someone I am 'Glad you have it resolved'?

Tags: phrase-usage

having a bit of a confusion how to properly format a sentence:

> Glad you have it resolved

But this seems right too:

> Glad you have resolved it

My gut tells me both are correct, although not sure about the first one. Or should it be

> Glad you got it resolved

What is the most proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the American English perspective, all three are grammatically correct.  The difference is primarily on where the emphasis is being placed, and by extension, the possible additional meanings that *might* be ***inferred***, without any further context.  However, remember that context is everything!

The first, "Glad you have it resolved" emphasizes that the speaker ("I") is glad, and that it's because the problem is resolved.  It's somewhat open as to how it got resolved.  It could be because "you" solved it, or because someone or something else solved it for you.

The second, "Glad you have resolved it" emphasizes the participation of you in getting it resolved, whether by direct action or indirectly by having someone or something else take care of (resolve) it for you.

However, the difference between those first two is very subtle, and open to disagreement among native English speakers.  Both are 100% grammatically correct for all meanings that either might have.  Both can mean that you solved the problem, or that you had someone or something else solve the problem, or that the problem just resolved itself without any action (e.g., the drought ended because it rained).

The third, "Glad you got it resolved" is effectively the same exact meaning as the first, but using a more informal (and more common in spoken word) verb "got" instead of "have".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the first actually means a technically different thing. In the first case, you are glad that the other person's issue is now resolved. In the second and third cases, however, you are glad that the other person resolved it.

The latter two are referencing the actual completion, as compared to the state of being completed.

Loosely (extremely loosely), I can imagine the same case in the scope of...washing a car (totally random example):

The first might equate to:

> I'm glad you've washed your car before.

Whereas the latter ones might equate to:

> I'm glad you washed your car that time.

Again, that's a pretty loose take on it, but that's an exaggerated example of the difference.

Realistically, which I suppose is probably most of what you're asking, I would probably say the last one. There are certain cases where I'd say the first, but mostly just for a different tone (I'm not really sure why, but it seems rushed to me--"glad you have it resolved, let's move on now").

Answer (score 0):

All the three sentences are grammatically correct, with the only difference mentioned below:

The first sentence "Glad you have it resolved"  means that "Glad  you get someone to resolve it for you". But I think you mean to say "Glad you have had it resolved". In this case, it express we "Glad you have got it resolved by somebody (somebody has resolved it for you)".

The second sentence "Glad you have resolved it" indicates that "you have resolved it yourself".

The third sentence "Glad you got it resolved" shows like the first one that "Glad you had it done by somebody (somebody resolved it for you)".

So, it's up to you which one to you, depending on the context. The use of "have" is a bit formal as in the first sentence.

Comment: I disagree with the above interpretations as a native American English speaker.  But native speakers of English in other countries may well agree.

Comment: @CXJ, I am not a native English speaker, but I am sure that "you got it resolved" doesn't have the same meaning as "you have it resolved". "got" is past whereas "have" is present. The right sentence is "you had it resolved".

Comment: No, that's not necessarily true because: "resolved" is a past participle and "have" is a helper verb.  In American English usage, we shade the meanings of when in the past something occurred using both present perfect (have done) and past perfect (had done) tenses.  Some languages do not have this behavior (for example German).  Also, it's colloquial to say "got", so strict grammar rules are not necessarily followed.  We are, however, talking very fine shades of perceived meaning here.  YMMV.  (Not sure why this Question popped up in my Inbox 8 years later!)